# combine multiple records into one line

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have a SQL Server 2005 table that records each step of a process as shown below

```
ResourceID    EventType         Time
ABC123        Job Activated     2013-01-08 10:01:31.000
ABC123        Download Complete 2013-01-08 10:03:32.000
ABC123        Job Complete      2013-01-08 10:07:42.000
XYZ789        Job Activated     2013-01-08 12:05:11.000
XYZ789        Download Complete 2013-01-08 12:08:52.000
XYZ789        Job Complete      2013-01-08 12:14:21.000
```

What I would like to do is display a result that has a single line for each `ResourceID` that shows the time for each event.

```
ResourceID  Job Activated             Download Complete        Job Complete
ABC123      2013-01-08 10:01:31.000   2013-01-08 10:03:32.000  2013-01-08 10:07:42.000
XYZ789      2013-01-08 12:05:11.000   2013-01-08 12:08:52.000  2013-01-08 12:14:21.000
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: You want to use PIVOT. I'm mobile so I can't write it up for you.

Comment: Check out the `PIVOT` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As the comments suggested, you can do this quite easily with `PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(ResourceID CHAR(6), EventType VARCHAR(32), [Time] DATETIME);

INSERT @x SELECT 'ABC123','Job Activated    ','2013-01-08 10:01:31.000'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ABC123','Download Complete','2013-01-08 10:03:32.000'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ABC123','Job Complete     ','2013-01-08 10:07:42.000'
UNION ALL SELECT 'XYZ789','Job Activated    ','2013-01-08 12:05:11.000'
UNION ALL SELECT 'XYZ789','Download Complete','2013-01-08 12:08:52.000'
UNION ALL SELECT 'XYZ789','Job Complete     ','2013-01-08 12:14:21.000';

SELECT ResourceID,[Job Activated],[Download Complete],[Job Complete]
FROM @x
PIVOT 
(
   MAX([Time]) FOR EventType IN (
    [Job Activated],[Download Complete],[Job Complete]
)) AS p;
```

Comment: I was just working on my answer, darn you for stealing my pivot

Comment: @bluefeet hey, you can't have `ALL` the `PIVOT`s. I'll leave the hard ones to you. :-)

Comment: Oh, I will still answer, just with alternatives. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to pivot the data:

```
select resourceid,
  max(case when EventType = 'Job Activated' then [time] end) as [Job Activated],
  max(case when EventType = 'Download Complete' then [time] end) as [Download Complete],
  max(case when EventType = 'Job Complete' then [time] end) as [Job Complete]
from yourtable
group by resourceid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65623/1).

Or you can use multiple joins on your table:

```
select ja.resourceid,
  ja.[time] as [Job Activated],
  dc.[time] as [Download Complete],
  jc.[time]  as [Job Complete]
from yourtable ja
left join yourtable dc
  on ja.resourceid = dc.resourceid
  and dc.EventType = 'Download Complete'
left join yourtable jc
  on ja.resourceid = jc.resourceid
  and jc.EventType = 'Job Complete'
where ja.EventType = 'Job Activated'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65623/3)